# Automated HDFS set up in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hdfs

I have been recently working on finding a cost-effective and quick way to set up an HDFS cluster on AWS. On one end, AWS EMR service is quick to be up and running, but is costly since it doesn't allow shutting down the cluster when not in use. On the other hand, one can manually [set up HDFS on EBS backed EC2 instances](https://www.novixys.com/blog/setup-apache-hadoop-cluster-aws-ec2/). Since these instances are EBS backed, data will be persisted even when the machines are shut down. This way is cost effective, but time taking. If the cluster contains say 50 machines, it will take lots of time to manually configure each. Also, the cluster machines will need to have fixed DNS names to run correctly after reboot.

Is there an AWS service that allows us to spin up an HDFS cluster within minutes and is also cost-effective?

Comment: Did you take a look at EFS? Cost-effective is really misleading, if you account for countless hours working on the cluster and fixing thing which will break for sure

Comment: You may find Cloudera Data Platform (CDP) Public Cloud offering interesting. https://www.cloudera.com/products/cloudera-data-platform.html